# How to set AllOfferListingsConsidered to true in GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN MWS products API

Tags: amazon-mws

I want top 20 offers of the ASIN which I am requesting.But in the response I am not getting 20 offers, I am getting less. And [AllOfferListingsConsidered] => false this is always set to false.

Please give me the solution to make  [AllOfferListingsConsidered] => true

Answer (score 0):

AllOfferListingsConsidered is a response element not a Request parameter as per this [link](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/products/Products_GetLowestOfferListingsForASIN.html), so i don't think you can set this parameter.